# Open/Mount XEN image formatted using NTFS

Tags: centos, xen, ntfs, image, raw-disk

I've created XEN image with dd some time ago.

The image is formatted using the NTFS

How it is possible to mount this image from Linux or Windows?

Thank You very much!

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to mount this as a loop device with a command similar to this one.
`mount /path/to/image /mnt -t ntfs -o loop`
or
`mount /path/to/image /mnt -t ntfs -o loop=/dev/loop3`

This will mount the image at /path/to/image /mnt as a loop device.  The first option will create the loop device on an unused loop device.  While the 2nd option will force the loop device to be setup on /dev/loop3.

You can get more options from the mount man pages or losetup man pages but losetup shouldn't be required to do this.

Comment: Thank You for your answer, at moment I'm getting "mount: unknown filesystem type 'ntfs'" Does it mean my kernel does not support NTFS?

Comment: NTFS support is provided as a FUSE file system so it's actually done in userspace.  Try using ntfs-3g instead of ntfs.